# How to share classes between two custom cocoa touch frameworks in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, shared-libraries, xcode7.3, cocoa-touch

I've created two custom cocoa touch frameworks, these two frameworks have  some same class(lets say "Framework-A","Framework-B" contains Class-A).If i use these both frameworks(Framework-A,Framework-B) in same project, i'm getting warning like this

**Class Class-A is implemented in both Framework-A and Framework-B. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**

Is there any chance to share the Class-A between two frameworks(Framework-A and Framework-B) instead of keeping Class-A in both frameworks?.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Add common classes to a Famrework or library and use that Library in both the Frameworks.

Comment: Thanks amit for quick response. I'm using one framework in both the frameworks ,for that also i'm getting same warning.

Answer (score 0):

Framework-A and Framework-B can both link to (but not embed) a Framework-C that contains the common classes (Class-A) that you want both Framework-A and Framework-B to have access to. The end application then needs to link to Framework-A and Framework-B, but embed all three frameworks in its bundle.